# How to read one line at a time with python

Tags: python

This is not from a file but this is a variable's value like the following:

```
fulltext = u'''test1,TEST1
test2,TEST2'''
```

Comment: oops. a line break was removed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lines = fulltext.splitlines()
```

handles `\r`, `\n` and their combination (works on other OS too):

```
>>> 'a\rb\nc\r\nd'.splitlines()
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for line in fulltext.split('\n'):
    # do something with the line
```

Answer (score 0):

Little unclear but is this what you're looking for?

```
string = """line one
   line two 
   line three"""
lines = string.split('\n')
```